# Evaluating a polynomial that includes a little-o constant exponent

Tags: algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

In a paper I am reading, the following assertion is made:
N is an odd, positive composite number. 
Let $I_1 = [\sqrt N - F^{2+o(1)} , \sqrt N + F^{2+o(1)}]$ hold the values of $x$ passed into the polynomial $Q(x)=x^2 - N$. Then the maximum absolute value of the $Q(x)$, for $x\in I$ is:  $\sqrt NF^{2+o(1)}$.

EDIT: F is a smoothness bound.

How is this final value obtained? 
When I pass $x = (\sqrt N + F^{2+o(1)}$) (which I believe to be the maximum value in $I$) into $Q$, I come up with $2\sqrt NF^{2+o(1)} + (F^{2+o(1)})^2$.

Comment: This notation is confusing - is $F$ a function of $N$, and what is the $o()$ being taken with respect to?  I strongly suspect that $F$ is in fact a function of $N$, in which case there are ways of making this make sense, but I'd need more context to say for sure.

Comment: Forgot to include that, thanks!

Comment: Could you please link the paper, if it's publicly available? That could help checking which assumptions were made.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2016-85-300/S0025-5718-2015-03058-0/S0025-5718-2015-03058-0.pdf . The statement is made in section 1.1

Comment: So indeed the $o(1)$ is taken with regard to $N\to\infty$ (or equivalently $F\to\infty$, as $F=L[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}] = \exp((\frac{1}{2}+o(1))\sqrt{\log N \log\log N})$ which goes to $\infty$ with $N$). Note also that $F$ is subpolynomial in $N$, i.e. $F=N^{o(1)}$ (asymptotically negligible in front of $N^\epsilon$ for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the two following hypotheses were made (we don't actually know what $F$ is from your post):

- $F$ satisfies $F>1$;
- $F = o(N^{1/4})$;
- the asymptotics are taken with regard to $F\to\infty$, and $F$ is allowed to be a function of $N$.

If so, you get
$$
2\sqrt{N} F^{2+o(1)} + F^{4+o(1)} = 2(1+o(1))\sqrt{N} F^{2+o(1)}
$$
and
$$
2(1+o(1))\sqrt{N} F^{2+o(1)} = \sqrt{N} F^{2+\frac{\ln (2(1+o(1)))}{\ln F}+o(1)}= \sqrt{N} F^{2+o(1)}.
$$

In short: the $o(1)$ hides a lot.

---

**Edit:** after looking at the paper (Section 1.1) [[1]](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2016-85-300/S0025-5718-2015-03058-0/S0025-5718-2015-03058-0.pdf):

Indeed the $o(1)$ is taken with regard to $N\to\infty$ (or equivalently $F\to\infty$, as $F=L[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}] = \exp((\frac{1}{2}+o(1))\sqrt{\log N \log\log N})$ which goes to $\infty$ with $N$). Note also that $F$ is subpolynomial in $N$, i.e. $F=N^{o(1)}$ (asymptotically negligible in front of $N^\epsilon$ for any fixed $\epsilon > 0$).

---

[1] *Quadratic sieving*, Thorsten Kleinjung. Math. Comp. 85 (2016), 1861-1873, 2015. DOI http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/mcom/3058

Comment: Actually, $F = O(N^{1/4})$ would be enough.

Comment: Yes, I see that now. O(1) does indeed hide a lot! Thanks

Comment: @1west I edited to add a bit more, after seeing the paper.